# Why appears only 2 sections, for the user enter data for each participant, and not 3? (if the user selects 3 tickets)

Tags: laravel

I have a single.blade.php where the user can select how many tickets want for each congress ticket type. For example if the conference has 3 ticket types (ticketype1, ticketype2, ticketype3) the user can select that he wants 1 ticket for the "ticketype2" and 2 tickets for the "ticketype3".

Then the user goes to the registration page. In this page the  user needs to introduce some data to register in a conference: first he needs to insert his information (name, etc), then if all_participants is "1" in the conference table he needs also to introduce  for each participant that he is registering the name and surname.

**The issue** is that if the user select that he wants for example 1 ticket for the "ticketype2" and 2 tickets for the "ticketype3" in the single.blade.php and click "Next" then in the registration page are only appear 2 sections for the user insert the name and surname of each participant, but it should be 3 because he selected 3 ticket in the previous page. Do you know why is only appearing 2?

// registration page form

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="name"
               name="name" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" required class="form-control" name="surname" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->surname : old('surname')}}">
    </div>

<!-- other form fields -->

<!-- then if the all_participants is 1 in the confernece table it should appear for each selected ticket a section for the user 
    that is doing the registration insert the name and surname of each paarticipant -->
    @if (!empty($all_participants))
        @if($all_participants == 1)
            @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
                {{$k}}
                <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6>
                <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                    <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                    <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endif

    <input type="submit" href="#" value="Next"/>
    </form>
```

**// single.blade.php page with form for the user to select the ticket types that he wants)**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('congresses.storeQuantity', ['id' => $cong->id, 'slug' => $cong->slug])}}">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          @foreach($ttypes as $ttype)
              <li class="list-group-item">
                      <span>{{$ttype->name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control" name="ttypes[{{ $ttype->name }}]">
                      <option selected></option>
                      @for ($i = $ttype->min; $i <= $ttype-> max; $i++)
                          <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                      @endfor
                  </select>
                  <span>{{$ttype->showPrice()}}</span>
              </li>
          @endforeach
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
  </form>
```

**storeQuantity Method:**

```
  public function storeQuantity(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        $request->validate([
            'ttypes' => ['required', 'array', new TicketTypeQuantity ],
        ]);

        $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

        $all_participants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){

            $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $ttype->price;

            $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
        }
        Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
        Session::put('all_participants' , $all_participants);
        return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a second foreach in your code; you need to ``foreach(range(1, $selectedType['quantity']) as $party)`` ...etc

Comment: Thanks, after "        foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){..."?

Comment: No, in your view you have a single foreach loop which doesn't take quantity into consideration

Comment: The issue should be because the quantity is stored associated with the ticket type. For example if the user select 1 ticket of the ticket type "ticketype1", 1 ticket of the ticket type "ticketype2" and 1 ticket of "ticketype3" it appears 3 sections for the user to insert the name and surname. But if the user select 2 tickets of a "ticketype1" and 1 ticket of "ticketype2" it only appear 2 sections for the user to insert the name and surname of each participant.

Comment: I understand; that's why I gave you the example using ``range(1, $TicketQuantity) `` which you should use before the echo of the fields

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you give an answer to accept it?